# Getting N-th day of month using DateTime()

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I need to get date of 10th day of current month. This way is not working:

```
<?php 
$date_start = new DateTime();
$date_start->modify('tenth day of this month');
echo $date_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";
?>
```

Results:

> Warning:  DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (tenth day
>   of this month ) at position 10 (o): The timezone could not be found in
>   the database in [...][...] on line 3

Of cource, I can use `date('Y-m-10')` but I need to make it **with DateTime() object**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found correct way:

```
<?php
$date_start = new DateTime();
$date_start->modify('first day of this month');
$date_start->modify('+9 days');
echo $date_start->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Result on 2018-09-30:

```
2018-09-10
```

Comment: this saved me, thanks.. it was really giving me a headache. you can just do it like 
```->modify('first day of this month')->modify('+8 day');```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`setDate`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php):

```
$date_start->setDate($date_start->format('Y'), $date_start->format('m'), 10);
echo $date_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";
```

Output:

```
2018-10-10 06:49:01
```

Comment: unfortunately `$date_start->modify('tenth day this month');` will give you unexcepted result 2018-10-01 (original date is 2018-09-30)

Comment: @Martin interesting... it's October here so it gives the right result. But when I try `tenth day next month` I get '2018-11-09' which is definitely not right!

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is `tenth day of this month` there is `first day of this month` :

If you want to do it with `DateTime` that way, you try double modify something like this:

```
  $date_start = new DateTime();
  $date_start->modify('first day of this month');
  $date_start->modify('+9 day');
  echo $date_start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";
```

Comment: yeah I see it, after i post my answer, posted before me 2 about two minute  :(